# Apply Class to Multiple Chart Objects- VBA

Tags: vba, excel, class, charts

I created a Class Module that captures click events on Chart Objects. It works as expected for one chart, but when I have multiple charts, only the last chart created maintains the functionality of the chart class. Below is the code I am using to apply the Chart Class to each chart object.

```
 Option Explicit

Global gclsDrill As New clsDrill

'Purpose: Initialize the Drill down class on each chart object

Sub InitChart()

Dim oChtObj As ChartObject
Dim oWorksheet As Worksheet


If oWorksheet Is Nothing Then Set oWorksheet = Sheets("Charts")

For Each oChtObj In oWorksheet.ChartObjects
    Set gclsDrill.Chart = oChtObj.Chart
Next

End Sub
```

I'm not sure why it works on only one chart object, and not every object and can't find any relevant information. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Probably because you are overwriting the Chart property of the gclsDrill object each time in the loop above. Therefore only the last will be kept at the end of the loop. I suspect you should create a new clsDrill Object each time in the loop. But I don't know the other details of your clsDrill class and so don't know if that is best - but my guess is that it will be OK.

Comment: Exactly right, thank you!

Comment: I've written a tutorial on [https://peltiertech.com/chart-events-microsoft-excel/](Chart Events in Microsoft Excel), if you're interested.

Comment: Awesome, thank you John Peltier. I'll definitely check that out. I've referenced your site for numerous things in the past, a fantastic resource!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a Global instance of your class, use a Collection: create a new instance of your class for each chart and add each instance to the Collection.

```
Option Explicit

Global colCls As Collection 'clsDrill

'Purpose: Initialize the Drill down class on each chart object

Sub InitChart()

    Dim oChtObj As ChartObject
    Dim oWorksheet As Worksheet

    Set colCls = New Collection

    If oWorksheet Is Nothing Then Set oWorksheet = Sheets("Charts")

    For Each oChtObj In oWorksheet.ChartObjects
        colCls.Add GetHandler(oChtObj.Chart)
    Next

End Sub

Function GetHandler(cht As Chart) As clsDrill
    Dim rv As New clsDrill
    Set rv.Chart = cht
    Set GetHandler = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim, that works perfectly. I suspected it was something like that but was unsure how to implement.